# android get compressed size of a file in a zipfile

Tags: android, compression, zip

Is there a way to get the **compressed** filesize of one file inside a zip archive?

`ZipEntry.getSize()` gives the uncompressed size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was easy to find out...

`zentr.getCompressedSize();`
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html#getCompressedSize()

Comment: Yes, I just found out. Excuse me.